# How to perform role based authorisations on nodejs express server with a good npm module?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, casl

I am working on a solution for authorization on a nodejs express server. I am fetching the role information of the logged in user by checking if the user has access to a specific access group by checking the ID Token value and see if that group name is present. I have to perform authorisations based on the role of the user by allowing certain user role to hit a specific endpoint.

What are the best authorization npm modules or techniques by which this can be achieved?

I have searched for a lot of them like casl, etc. but there seem to be a lot of way and this is just shooting up the confusion bar. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of permission management is about what user can do with data stored in db.

That’s why, I would recommend define permissions on resources/models/tables. You can group multiple permissions under one role. This is how you will get RBAC.

To get more details check this examples:

- [casl express](https://github.com/stalniy/casl-examples/tree/master/packages/express-blog)
- [casl rbac static permissions](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/cookbook/roles-with-static-permissions)
- [casl rbac user defined permissions](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/cookbook/roles-with-persisted-permissions)

If this is too confusing, just use http keywords (get/post/etc) as actions and `req.url` as subject. So, eventually you will have something like:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const ability = defineUserAbility(req.user);
  
  if (ability.can(req.method, req.url)) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.status(403).end()
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Followed the links in this answer at last and got the thing implemented. :)